# How to disable IssueRegistry#vendor for specific library and pass ci check in Android?

Tags: android, android-lint

I have this error when do ciCheckDebug:

```
jetified-butterknife-runtime-10.2.3\jars\lint.jar does not specify a vendor; see IssueRegistry#vendor
```

Cannot find, how to disable it without abortOnError=false for everything? I know, this library is deprecated, but I cannot remove it from the project. Please help!

Comment: Hey there, Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot do that, but AFAIK this is a warning not an error. So it shouldn't break your build. This is due to old Lint version dependency in ButterKnife. You'd have to go there and bump the dependency (or make an issue for somebody else to do that). Since the project is basically dead - the release is unlikely. You should migrate to `ViewBinding` or something else ASAP anyway